# How to avoid repeating certain arguments for many functions? (Python)

Tags: python, function, variables, dry

I am writing this app using Evernote API, and find myself calling many functions with the same few arguments repeatedly. Any way I can avoid this without using global variables?

```
def get_all_notes(dev_token, noteStore):

def find_notes(notebook, dev_token, noteStore):

def main():
    dev_token = ...
    noteStote = ...
    notes = get_all_notes(dev_token, noteStore)
    notes_from_notebook1 = find_notes(notebooks[0], dev_token, noteStore)
```

Comment: You can try to store the arguments in some type of container. That might reduce the number of arguments that you enter each time. Not sure if that is what you're looking for though

Comment: If you never use a `noteStore` without a `dev_token` (...naming convention?) and they have the same lifecycle then why not wrap them both into one object and pass *that* around? This isn't really specific to Python: https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-parameter-list

Comment: Can you give a better description of what your problem is and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use aggregation: Define a class that holds `dev_token` and `noteStore` as data members.

Comment: Do you ever use one more than one dev token or note store? If not, that's a good indication that you don't really need a class, and that global variables aren't entirely inappropriate. (Think of a module with functions that access shared module-level globals as a singleton instance of an implicit class.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using the same arguments over and over, and they don't change. Maybe it calls for making them a class?

```
class MyNotesController:
    def __init__(self, dev_token, noteStore):
        self.dev_token = dev_token
        self.noteStore = noteStore

    def get_all_notes(self):
        # Use self.dev_token and self.noteStore


    def find_notes(self, notebook):
        # Use self.dev_token and self.noteStore

def main():
    dev_token = ...
    noteStote = ...
    my_ctrl = MyNotesController(dev_token, noteStote)
    notes = my_ctrl.get_all_notes()
    notes_from_notebook1 = my_ctrl.find_notes(notebooks[0])
```